# How to get select option static value to controller

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf

Here the  Select /Combobox static value pass to  controller using script is not working properly, the script alert is working.

Html code

```
<select id="propertyfor" onchange="onPropertyforChange();">
<option value="0">Select Property For</option>
<option value="SELL" id="1" th:value="${'SELL'}">SELL</option>
<option value="RENT" id="2" th:value="${'RENT'}">RENT</option>
</select>
```

script code

```
function onPropertyforChange() {
    alert("HI");
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        url : '/RealEstate/selectedPropertyfor.html',
        data : ({
            id : $('#propertyfor').val()
        })    
    });
}
```

the alert shows here but the controller println not working

Controller

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = ("/selectedPropertyfor.html"))
public void getpropertyFor(@RequestParam("propertyfor") int propertyfor) {
    System.out.println(propertyfor+"QQQQQQQQQQQQQ");
}
```

if you know about this please share answer here.

Comment: Also paramater should be string not int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the value of the select with the property name of `id`, not `propertyfor`. Also, your `data` syntax is a little odd.

```
data: {
    propertyfor : $('#propertyfor').val()
}
```